# Atomically increment integer and update another column based on result

Tags: sql

I have the following table

### Job

```
TOTAL_PARTS: int
FINISHED_PARTS: int
STATUS: "pending"|"ready"
```

I am running this query in a multi-threaded environment, so I have to be careful that operations don't affect one another.

### Question

In one SQL command (if possible), I would like to:

1. Increment "FINISHED_PARTS"
2. Set "STATUS" to "ready" IF FINISHED_PARTS = TOTAL_PARTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE foo_table
SET
    FINISHED_PARTS = FINISHED_PARTS + 1,
    STATUS = CASE WHEN FINISHED_PARTS + 1 = TOTAL_PARTS THEN 'ready' ELSE STATUS END
WHERE ...
```

MySQL-only shorter version:

```
UPDATE foo_table
SET
    FINISHED_PARTS = FINISHED_PARTS + 1,
    STATUS = IF(FINISHED_PARTS + 1 = TOTAL_PARTS, 'ready', STATUS)
WHERE ...
```

Comment: Thank you - am using Postgres and should have specified that. Am experimenting now and will let you know what ends up working. Thanks